# ASP MVC project takes forever to load in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis, model-view-controller

I have a simple MVC .NET 4.5 project, practically the Visual Studio template, and when I start debugging it takes forever to load (sometimes it times out) and IIS consumes a huge amount of memory.

I have read all the posts about this, memory leaks: it is the template; Offline Symbol Loading: did that without effect; antivirus: I don't have it; indexing: removed it; firewall: removed it...

And still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error, I'v discovered that enabling the 32-Bit Application in the advanced settings of my application pool would solve my problem.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?
And how to detect it?
Because it took me 3 days to figure this out and there is no indication that this might be a problem.

[image: App Pool Advanced Settings]

Comment: what is the version of VS and IIS? Is the application configured as a 32 bit application or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the processor is slowing you down. On a hardware level the process can receive instructions in 2 different forms, either 32-bit or 64-bit. If running in 64-bit mode it can still use 32-bit instructions; it's just slower because it needs to check whether the instructions are written in 32-bit or 64-bit. What **really** slows it down is when the program is written in 32-bit and IIS is running in 64 bit mode. IIS will then check every set of instructions it receives for the length of the instruction. This is because it theoretically could receive a 64-bit instruction at any time (even though we know that the program is written in 32-bit mode). Now IIS will do this check for every set of instructions or (for simplicity) every line of code. You could see how this operation isn't exactly slow in and of itself would, over hundreds lines of code, slow your program down dramatically.